# Mixed Data Types Matlab Tables

Tags: matlab, data-cleaning, matlab-table

I wish to use the `makeValidName` function on the following data:

```
Id  Val Random          Desc
a   1.1 0.036835624 Bread Cheese
b   2.2 0.020442492 Fish Bread
c   -3.3    0.020050676 Cheese Fish
d   #N/A    0.017619332 Bread Cheese
e   -5.4    0.014973153 Fish Bread
f   6.6 0.014648887 Cheese Fish
g   -7.6    0.014071844 Bread Cheese
h   8   0.014013118 Fish Bread
```

However when I import the table (read from xlsx using readtable) it looks like this:

inputData =

```
 Id             Val              Random          Desc     
____    ____________________    ________    ______________

'a '    '1.1'                   0.036836    'Bread Cheese'
'b'     '2.2'                   0.020442    'Fish Bread'  
'c'     '-3.3'                  0.020051    'Cheese Fish' 
'd'     'ActiveX VT_ERROR: '    0.017619    'Bread Cheese'
'e'     '-5.4'                  0.014973    'Fish Bread'  
'f'     '6.6'                   0.014649    'Cheese Fish' 
'g'     '-7.6'                  0.014072    'Bread Cheese'
'h'     '8'                     0.014013    'Fish Bread'
```

How do I prevent it from turning the entries in `Val` from numbers to strings? This makes it impossible to use `makeValidName`. I need to apply `makeValidName` across all rows and columns as the tables are very large and it is not feasible to name the appropriate columns individually. What would then be the most elegant way of achieving this?

Current code:

```
varnames = inputData.Properties.VariableNames;
for ii = 1:length(varnames)

inputData.(varnames{ii})= matlab.lang.makeValidName(inputData.(varnames{ii}));

end
```

Produces the error:

> Error using matlab.lang.makeValidName (line 72) First input must be
>   string or vector cell array of strings.

and produces undesirable results in columns such as `Val`:

inputData =

```
Id            Val             Random         Desc     
___    __________________    ________    _____________

'a'    'x1_1'                0.036836    'BreadCheese'
'b'    'x2_2'                0.020442    'FishBread'  
'c'    'x_3_3'               0.020051    'CheeseFish' 
'd'    'ActiveXVT_ERROR_'    0.017619    'BreadCheese'
'e'    'x_5_4'               0.014973    'FishBread'  
'f'    'x6_6'                0.014649    'CheeseFish' 
'g'    'x_7_6'               0.014072    'BreadCheese'
'h'    'x8'                  0.014013    'FishBread'
```

Comment: Are you sure you understand the purpose of `makeValidName`? The behavior shown for the `Val` column is consistent with the behavior of the function.

Comment: Yes. I expect it to do that except that I need it to do that for non-numerical entries only. Because of the #NA readtable has translated the entire Val column into strings even though all entries but one are numbers. This leads to the numbers being further transformed under `makeValideName`. So ideally readtable needs to correctly distinguish number or string columns or I need to transform/ clean up the data post-import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems like utilizing Excel in the middle is creating more of a headache. I would recommend utilizing `basic` mode which will alleviate some of the parsing errors.

From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html#input_argument_namevalue_basic):

> `basic` mode is the default for systems without Excel for Windows. In
>   `basic` mode, `readtable`:
>
> - Reads XLS, XLSX, XLSM, XLTX, and XLTM files only.
> - Does not support the `'Range'` name-value pair argument when reading XLS files.
> - Imports all dates as Excel serial date numbers. Excel serial date numbers use a different reference date than MATLAB® date numbers.

This allows us to utilize the `TreatAsEmpty` name-value pair argument since it will correctly parse the numeric columns.

```
inputData = readtable('test.xlsx', 'Basic', 1, 'TreatAsEmpty', '#N/A');
```

Which returns for the sample case:

```
inputData = 

    Id     Val      Random          Desc     
    ___    ____    ________    ______________

    'a'     1.1    0.036836    'Bread Cheese'
    'b'     2.2    0.020442    'Fish Bread'  
    'c'    -3.3    0.020051    'Cheese Fish' 
    'd'     NaN    0.017619    'Bread Cheese'
    'e'    -5.4    0.014973    'Fish Bread'  
    'f'     6.6    0.014649    'Cheese Fish' 
    'g'    -7.6    0.014072    'Bread Cheese'
    'h'       8    0.014013    'Fish Bread'
```

Theoretically this should mean that the numeric data columns are `double` arrays and the strings remain in `cell` arrays. Therefore, to use [`matlab.lang.makeValidName`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.lang.makevalidname.html) you can test each column with [`iscell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/iscell.html) to see if it's a cell array:

```
varnames = inputData.Properties.VariableNames;
for ii = 1:length(varnames)
    if iscell(inputData.(varnames{ii}))
        % If they're strings they're in a cell array
        inputData.(varnames{ii})= matlab.lang.makeValidName(inputData.(varnames{ii}));
    end
end
```

Which returns:

```
inputData = 

    Id     Val      Random         Desc     
    ___    ____    ________    _____________

    'a'     1.1    0.036836    'BreadCheese'
    'b'     2.2    0.020442    'FishBread'  
    'c'    -3.3    0.020051    'CheeseFish' 
    'd'     NaN    0.017619    'BreadCheese'
    'e'    -5.4    0.014973    'FishBread'  
    'f'     6.6    0.014649    'CheeseFish' 
    'g'    -7.6    0.014072    'BreadCheese'
    'h'       8    0.014013    'FishBread'
```

Comment: Nice solution. Works great. Thanks!